# Selenium with typescript

Tags: java, typescript, selenium, frameworks

What is the advantage of using selenium with Typescript over selenium with Java.
Which type of web applications can be automated with Selenium+Typescript and why these cant be done with selenium+java?

Answer (score 1):

No major benefits in my opinion, that's my tl,dr;

I can think of a couple of options you might have though:

You might be able to integrate the test framework with the front-end application repository. This can be useful if you are using a Typescript based framework (like React for example) and you can potentially use that to import the application data (for example stub responses for APIs that the developers are using for their dev work, assuming they are available there... just an example) and use that for testing the front-end code in isolation without the API dependencies.

The other reason I can think of is that if you did the above you can potentially execute your test cases as part of the CI of the front-end code, for example you can run a subset of the test cases with pull requests to make sure all is green before merging in the main branch.

Really you can do all the above with an external repo written in Java (hence, no major benefits)

Answer (score 0):

In term of automation -> Type scripts basically used by tools like protractor which actually used javascript itself but provide extension to write scripts in typescript which then converted to javascript and pass further for execution. 
The main use of typescript is its oops based so its easy to write maintainable code.

Protractor is a nodejs plug-in which use selenium wedriverjs binding internally

**Your second question why typescripts:**

Basically Protractor is use on Angular-JS client side websites. still you can automate non-angular websites also using Protractor 
Normally selenium **do not** have the capability to understand if the element is ready due to even after page load completed, JavaScript is still working behind for Anugular/JS based website so Protractor provide wrapper which having additional functionality like `waitForAngular`

Additionally Protractor provide more locators identify strategy which is not present in normal selenium with java or c#

Refer:

http://www.protractortest.org/#/locators

As Protractor is build on wedriverjs we also need to script for it on JavaScript or typescript. basically even if you code in typescript internally it will convert it into typescript. people prefer typescript as it follows full oops unlike like JavaScript

Source:

http://www.protractortest.org/#/

there are more js based framework is in the market like:

- WebdriverIO
- Nightwatch

Now java also comes up with many library like JSWaiter etc which claim they can handle js based client side websites with java + selenium as well

Comment: This answer is totally irrelevant.  Did you read the question?

Comment: hmm .. I tried to rephrase my answer .. may this time it helps what I want to say